# Postgresql dynamic query in COPY stament with psql command

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get maintenance query from windows command line psql with COPY statement.(Windows 2012). The query produces maintenance query as output file. After that I wish to import maintenance query (reindex.sql) and execute with a scheduler. But I couldn't find it out why I couldnt execute script. There should be a  comma trick which I couldn't solve.

```
psql -U postgres -c "COPY( SELECT 'REINDEX TABLE "' || schemaname || '"."' || relname || '";'FROM pg_stat_all_tables ORDER BY n_dead_tup DESC)TO 'E:\scripts\maintenance\reindex.sql';"
```

Comment: Could you describe "does not work" in some more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`format():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

```
psql -U postgres -c ^
"COPY ( ^
SELECT format('REINDEX TABLE %s.%s', schemaname, relname) ^
FROM pg_stat_all_tables ^
ORDER BY n_dead_tup DESC) ^
TO 'E:\scripts\maintenance\reindex.sql'"
```